# How would one find the number that is a given percentage between two numbers?

Tags: percentages

Assume I have two numbers, say, 23 and 1150. Also assume I have a given percentage, say, 32.6%. What formula would I use to find the number that is 32.6% between 23 and 1150?

Comment: You could use a linear interpolation. Let the first number be $a$ and the second be $b$, and let the fraction be $t$ (i.e. you want to find the number that is $t$ of the way from $a$ to $b$). Then, your number is $(1-t)a+tb$.

Comment: 23 + (1150 - 23) x 32.6 / 100 = 435.482, because 23 + (1150 - 23) x 0 / 100 = 23 and 23 + (1150 - 23) x 100 / 100 = 1150.

Comment: You've made a calculator error. The answer is $390.402$.

Comment: It is not particularly clear what saying "x % between a and b" is supposed to mean and it isn't a common mathematical expression.  As with all math we need to clearify what we mean... and then we do it.  If we mean: The difference between a and b is an amount and we want a the number than is x% of that amount above a ... then that is: a + x%of(b-a).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number that is $x\%$ of the way between $a$ and $b$ is given by $$a + (b-a)\cdot \frac x{100}.$$

For example, the number $30\%$ of the way between $10$ and $20$ is $$10 + (20-10) \cdot \frac{30}{100} = 13.$$

Why this formula?  The factor $b-a$ gives you the length of the interval.  The factor $\dfrac x{100}$ tells you how much of this length you need in order to get $x\%$.  Finally, the term $a$ ensures that you start moving "$x\%$ of the way into the interval" from the beginning of the interval.